# How does connection recovery work in iOS GoogleCast framework

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

We are working on a chromecast sender app of iOS. We noticed that the connection to receiver doesn't recover if there is connection lost happened for around 20 seconds (e.g Turn on flight mode for 20 seconds and then turn it off). Does anyone know how GoogleCast framework handles the connection recovery? Is there any retry mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#automatic_reconnection), the Cast framework adds reconnection logic to automatically handle reconnection in many subtle corner cases, such as:

- Recover from a temporary loss of WiFi
- Recover from device sleep
- Recover from backgrounding the app
- Recover if the app crashed

You may refer in this [Restoring sessions](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_sender#restoring-sessions) documentation:

> According to the [UX Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ux_guidelines), if the sender application becomes disconnected from the media route, such as when the user or the operating system kills the application without the user first disconnecting from the Cast device, then the application must restore the session with the receiver when the sender application starts again.
>
> To handle this use case the sender application has to persist the route ID and session ID during the Cast app life cycle. If the user explicitly disconnects from a Cast device, these persisted data should be cleared to avoid the automatic reconnection logic to be invoked when the application starts again.

Hope this helps!